# Is there a way to check if a user is still fan of my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently am making a list of my fans who communicated with my page and I store their data in a personal database. But now I was wondering if there is a way to see if a user is still fan of my page.

Example: A user likes my page and posts something on my wall. 2 weeks later, the same user unlikes my page and I update my fan database. I will still get his name in the query because he once posted a message on my wall. Any solutions or ideas?

Note: The user does not need to login to an application or give permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to check if a user is a fan of your Page. The user would have to authorize an App with `user_likes`, and you would not get that permission approved just for checking the like status.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That was the answer that I feared. I have the idea to make an app for my page to ask users for permissons, so I can get more detailed information and to know for sure they like the page. Do you think that will work?

Comment: as i said, you will not get user_likes approved just for checking if the user liked your page. like gating is not allowed anyway.